# Count number of occurrences of People Chip in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Does google sheet support counting of People Chips? If not, is there an easy way to convert all the personal chips in a sheet to strings?

Answer (score 0):

in some scenarios, you can use `ISEMAIL` like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISEMAIL(A1:A10))
```

tho it's worth mentioning, that it does not differentiate between regular email in cell and people chips

[image]

and too convert chips into strings you can use `TO_TEXT`

```
=INDEX(TO_TEXT(A1:A10))
```